# How to implement a graph with different types of Nodes?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm a very much new to C++ programming and I'm trying to implement a Scene Graph in C++.

There should be a Node class, which is the super class (and an abstract class) and some child classes like Geometry, Group, Transformation etc. I need to implement a graph, where either of sub class objects can be nodes. There can be one or many children per node. (There are common methods and attributes as well as different methods and attributes in sub classes.)

I need to create a graph where I can add,remove nodes and execute their common methods regardless to their type.

Can anyone please share any ideas or methodologies to implement such graph?

EDIT : This is a sample definitions of my work. (I only add the header contents. But if the implementation is needed, I will provide.)

node.h

```
using namespace std;

#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node{
public:
  Node();
  virtual ~Node() = 0;
  Node(string name);

  string getName();
  void setName(string name);

  vector<Node*> getChildrenNodes();
  size_t getChildNodeCount();
  Node* getChildNodeAt(int i);
  void setChildernNodes(vector<Node*> children);

  void addChildNode(Node* child);

  virtual string getNodeType()=0; // to make this class abstract

protected:
  string name;
  vector<Node*> children;
};
#endif
```

geometry.h

```
class Geometry :  public Node {
public:
    Geometry();
    ~Geometry();
    string getNodeType();
    // Method overrides and other class specific methods.
};
```

graph.h

```
#include "node.h"

class Graph{
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    void addNode(Node* parent,Node* child);
    void addNode(Node* child);
    Node* getRoot();
private:
    Node* root;
};
```

This is my main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "node.h"
#include "graph.h"

int main(){

    Graph sg;
    Geometry g1;

    sg.addNode(g1); // error: no matching function for call to ‘Graph::addNode(Geometry&)’

    return 0;
}
```

If you can, show where I went wrong.

Comment: You already mention a very reasonable approach: edges (whatever representation you might use for them) point to `Node*` and you get polymorphism out of these pointers.

Comment: Then what can I do, when an element of the graph is given and I need to execute specific method? How do I know which type of object is that? Can is simply use `typeOf` method for that?

Comment: What specific method? What should happen to nodes that don't have this method because they are the wrong type? If you want to get a useful answer you should explain in detail.

Comment: I edited the question and added a sample code.

Comment: Replace `sg.addNode(g1); // error: ... ` with `Geometry *ptr = new Geometry(); sg.addNode(ptr);` You need a pointer as a parameter, not an object.

Comment: try `sg.addNode(&g1);` - your methods needs a pointer, no reference. Furthermore, make `Node`'s destructor virtual

Comment: Thanks. It works. At least for now. If I have more problems, I will comment here. :)
PS : Can I use this same class structure for Visitor Design Pattern ?

Comment: @walle that'll work in main() function but not where g1 can go out of scope and invalidate pointer &g1. You need to be careful what pointer you pass in addNode()

Comment: `~Node` should be virtual.

Comment: @dmitri, but then he should use smart pointers!